# Angular Dart passing data from route service into a controller

Tags: routes, dart, angular-dart

I'm struggling to find a way to get data from my router into my controller. The enter method on the route is correctly grabbing the data from the service, as the print method shows the JSON response in the console.

My Module looks like this:

```dart
class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule () {
    type(UsersService);
    type(UsersController);
    type(RouteInitializerFn, implementedBy: MyAppRouteInitializer);
    factory(NgRoutingUsePushState,
        (_) => new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
  }
}
```

and a simplified version of my router

```dart
class MyAppRouteInitializer {

  final UsersService _userService;

  MyAppRouteInitializer(this._userService);

  void call(Router router, ViewFactory views) {
     views.configure({
        'users': ngRoute(
         path: '/users',
         view: 'views/users/users.html',
         mount: {
            'list': ngRoute(
             path: '',
             view: 'views/users/list.html',
             enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) {
                _userService.all((HttpResponse response){
                    var data = response.data['body'];
                    print(data);
                });
             }
          }
        )
      });
   }
}
```

At the moment my controller is pretty much empty just looks like this

```dart
@NgController(
    selector: '[users-controller]',
    publishAs: 'userCtrl'
)

class UsersController {
     var list;

     UsersController() {

     }

}
```

Any help on how to get the service response into the controller would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do this in the route enter event handler?
You don't even use any information from the route or the event.
You could just register the `UserService` with your Module an let it inject to your `UserController`.

```dart
class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(UsersService);
  }
}

@NgController(
  selector: '[users-controller]',
  publishAs: 'userCtrl'
)

class UsersController {
  var list;

  UsersService _usersService;

  UsersController(this._usersService) {
    _userService.all((HttpResponse response){
                    var data = response.data['body'];
                    print(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I had done in the first place, I'm new to AngularDart and Dart itself. I was thinking along the lines of resolving the request before the route change like you can in Angular.js. But that's much simpler

Comment: I don't know Angular.js but there seem to be quite some differences. Much of this is planned (as I heard) to be ported to Angular.js.

Comment: Awesome, Angular.js is a nice framework. But the features in Dart are a lot better, from what I have seen so far. Only picked up dart a few days ago so it's pretty easy to learn. Thanks